# Dragon Head - What's its purpose?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I didn't found information on the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mob_head) about the dragon head (waited some time now).

I own one of this heads and wear it, but it doesn't seem to serve any purpose as far as my experience went. Except for my friends being jealous that I own one (maybe that's the purpose :P).

Does it provide any advantage (like the pumpkin head which makes endermen totally neutral)?

Comment: It doesn't need a purpose. It just looks really cool.

Answer (score 2):

You were correct in saying that except for your friends being jealous there is no point. It's just an awesome trophy (or killed one of your friends who had a skull). Also, when powered with redstone it will open and close it's mouth repeatedly.

Comment: actually, you get them from end city ships, not the enderdragon. Same place as elytras